# Get Request in a Smart Contract from an API

Tags: json, blockchain, smartcontracts, chainlink, get-request

I am trying to fetch data from an API. I have followed all the necessary steps required according to chain link docs.

[image: API response in Postman:]

```
function requestFirstId() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );

        
        req.add(
            "get",
            "https://pi360.net/site/api/student_meta_data.php?institute_id=mietjammu&student_id=NTI5Mg==&key=QUFqSDg3Kjk2cC00NCNAaFc="
        );

        
        req.add("path", "0,student"); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format
        st
        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }
```

Not able to retrieve Data from API in the Smart Contract

I was expecting an get-request response

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that either:

1. Your API endpoint is down
2. The data you are trying to fetch is too large, or your contract's fulfill function is otherwise too complex, and uses too much gas (>500,000).
3. The Chainlink oracle you are pointing to is down.

If you're sure your API is online, and the data you are writing to your contract within your contract's fulfill / callback function is rather small (ie, basic `uint256` or `bytes32` string), I'd recommend pointing your contract to a different Chainlink oracle.

To find a Chainlink oracle, you can either:

1. Join the Chainlink Official Discord server, post your request to the **#operator-requests** channel, and wait for a willing oracle to reply.
2. Browse the website of a reputable oracle company (at LinkWell Nodes we provide sample smart contracts, job IDs, and oracle addresses on our website, as do many others).

You can also try signing up for Chainlink Functions if you don't mind coding up your request logic in JavaScript, but please keep in mind that the gas limit for Chainlink Functions requests is even smaller (300,000).

Let me know if any of this helps!